# How prove this $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{C_{m}^{k}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{m}+1^m}{m+2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{C_{m}^{k}}=\dfrac{(-1)^{m}+1^m}{m+2}$$

where $C_{m}^{k}=\dfrac{m!}{(m-k)!k!}$

This problem is my frend ask me,I think we can prove by case$:m=2n,m=2n+1$

Thank you everyone can nice methods.

Comment: oh.Thank you ,I have edit

Comment: If $m$ is odd, note that the summands for $k$ and $m-k$ cancel.

Comment: Thank you,But for $m$ is even,I can't prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{1}{C^m_k}=(m+1)\frac{\Gamma(m-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(m+2)}=(m+1)B(m-k+1,k+1),$$
the sum can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&(m+1)\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(-1)^{k+1}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^k\right)(1-x)^mdx=\\
=&(m+1)\int_0^1\left[x(1-x)^m+(-1)^m(1-x)x^m\right]dx=\\=&(m+1)\left(1+(-1)^m\right)B(2,m+1)=\\
=&\frac{1+(-1)^m}{m+2}.
\end{align}
Here $B(p,q)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}$ denotes Euler beta function, and the summation over $k$ was performed using geometric series.

Comment: It's very nice.Thank you